# Copy fields from a mysql view to a mysql table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, view

I have a view that calculates the number of appointments scheduled in the last 30 days, 365 days, and the number of missed appointments in the last 30 days.

I need to get these data into a table so that I can populate a reports module (I thought I could do it from the view, but it turns out I can not).

Parent table: client
Child table: appointment
View: total
New table: apt_total

Within mysql I can do an insert or update just fine, but when I put it into php it does not work as planned. There may be 15-20 appointments for a client in a 30 day period, but I don’t want multiple entries in the apt_total table because then the reports module prints out 15-20 different running totals. I would like to keep it where the apt_total table only has as many rows as I have clients.

All of the tables have an “id” field which links back to the client table.

```
INSERT INTO apt_total (id, name, Last30days, Last365days, Alltime, NoShow) SELECT id, name, Last30days, Last365days, Alltime, NoShow from total3;

UPDATE apt_total, total3 SET apt_total.Last30days = total3.Last30days, apt_total.Last365days = total3.Last365days, apt_total.Alltime = total3.Alltime, apt_total.NoShow = total3.NoShow WHERE apt_total.id = total3.id;
```

QUESTION: What is the most efficient way of executing this in php?

I’ve been at this for over 24 hours and I feel like I am going to crack. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PHP code:

```
function afterSave(&$record)
        {
            $app =& Dataface_Application::getInstance();
            $record = $app->getRecord();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO apt_total (id, name, Last30days, Last365days, Alltime, NoShow) SELECT id, name, Last30days, Last365days, Alltime, NoShow from total3";
            $res = xf_db_query($sql, df_db());
    }
```

Comment: Offering a minimal yet accurate SQLFiddle to your question will invariably improve the speed and quality of the feedback that you receive.  Please take the time to make this offering and post in your question.  You will be glad you did.  (and we don't need that `Thanks, Steven` sign-off in your question.  just the facts, jack)

Comment: Since you say the problem doesn't exist when you run the queries in MySQL, but does exists when you execute from PHP, your problem is likely in the PHP. Please post the complete routine, or at least enough of it so we can see everything relevant to the sql operations.

Comment: The reason it does not work "as planned" is because I end up with multiple entries in the apt_total table. I'll add the php code above.